# how to get object id in firebase android?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase database. I have shown user names in list view. and when i clicked on any list item I want to show more information on the other activity. So I want to get object id of particular clicked item.

Here's the image [when user click I want to get unique id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd2L7.jpg)

Comment: Have you seen Google examples? Check this: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android

Comment: Share the database structure

Comment: you can get particular child which you are stored in list than after if you getting one perticular child data

Answer (score 0):

First of all, need some clarification on how you are listing the usernames on the listview. That might help to give an answer similar to the way that you have followed. As your way of solving things is not mentioned, here's how I would go about:

> While listing usernames, make sure the query which gets your usernames also gets the ID of the users. Then just store one more variable in the item class in your list view for that user ID, so when the user clicks an user, send the user ID variable in the clicked item class to another activity(one way is to use bundle and put it in Intent Extras) and query for that user ID in the firebase which will give you the required info.

Hope that helps.